# Hadoop MapReduce recursion with several outputs?

Tags: recursion, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I have map reduce program which take output of reducer in every recursion step. but i also need to output another results in every recursion .

input1--->Map1-->Reduce1--> output1 and output11

output1--->Map2-->Reduce2--> output2 and output22

output2--->Map3-->Reduce3--> output3 and output33

output3--->Map4-->Reduce4--> output4 and  output44

as Final  output i need : output11,output22,output33,output44 and output4

like this each step has 2 output files in which 1 goes to next iteration and other goes to output.

I am using SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat .

any help thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have a map reduce job for each recursive step, and use the output file of 1 recursive step for the next map reduce job